# What is default header content-type for http post method in curl form?

Tags: python, ajax, curl, flask

I am using a curl command with POST method using html Form with attribute- values. I am using flask framework. My content type is not application-json.

The command I give with the headers is as follows:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -F "description=description" -F "file_name=@curl_commands.md"  -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/upload_doc
-H 'workflow_id:1' -H 'change_workflow:Y'
```

What should I specify for the Content-type:? This is required for the js ajax call.

Comment: Jivan thx for the clarity!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is clear at this url: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`

Comment: This answer answers the question but not the title of the question.. if that makes sense. if we do `curl -X POST -d @somefile`, what is the default content-type?

Comment: @Tommy Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75359262/17865804).