# FastAPI: Why Content-Type header is required in a JSON POST request?

Tags: python, json, curl, fastapi, content-type

I have the following FastAPI application:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel as Schema
from fastapi import FastAPI

api = FastAPI()

class User(Schema):
    firstname: str
    lastname: str
    age: int | None = None


@api.post('/user')
def user_selection(user: User):
    return {'data': f'{user.firstname} {user.lastname} age: {user.age}'}
```

The main file is called `file.py`, so I run the uvicorn server like this:

```
uvicorn file:api --reload
```

Through another console, I send this request:

```
curl -X 'POST' -i 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user' -d '{firstname":"mike", "lastname":"azer"}'
```

but, I get this error:

```json
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
date: Sun, 05 Feb 2023 16:01:14 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 88
content-type: application/json

{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}
```

Why is that?

If, however, I set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` in my request:

```
curl -X 'POST'   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{
  "firstname": "aaa",
  "lastname": "zzz"
}'
```

**it works** just fine.

Why do I need the header? When I do a `GET` request, I don't have  to add a header and it works. What's the difference with the `POST` request?

Comment: `When I do a get request, i don't have header` When you do a GET request you don't have a body either. `why do i need a header?` To tell the server what kind of data you're sending.

Comment: `-d '{firstname":"mike", "lastname":"azer"}'` You're missing a double quote mark before `firstname`.

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Why Content-Type header is required in a JSON POST request?"***

A: According to [`curl`'s documentation](https://everything.curl.dev/http/post/content-type):

> POSTing with curl's `-d` option will make it include a default header
> that looks like `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
> That is what your typical browser will use for a plain POST.
>
> Many receivers of POST data do not care about or check the
> Content-Type header.
>
> If that header is not good enough for you, you should, of course,
> replace that and instead provide the correct one. Such as if you POST
> JSON to a server and want to more accurately tell the server about
> what the content is:
>
> ```
> curl -d '{json}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://example.com
> ```

Hence, the reason for `'Content-Type: application/json'` header being required when sending a `POST` request containing JSON data is simply because `curl` by default uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) to encode the data that forms the body of the request—this is what a browser typically uses when submitting an HTML `<form>`.

If, however, `files` are also included in the request, then `multipart/form-data` content type is **automatically** used by `curl`—the same applies to using Python requests, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804) (as for HTML forms, you need to **manually** specify the `enctype`, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797993/17865804))—as per [`curl`'s documentation](https://everything.curl.dev/http/post/binary):

> **Posting binary**
>
> When reading data to post from a file, `-d` will strip out carriage return and newlines. Use `--data-binary` if you
> want curl to read and use the given file in binary exactly as given:
>
> ```
> curl --data-binary @filename http://example.com/
> ```

I would also suggest you to take a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74542722/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804), as well as use the [interactive Swagger UI autodocs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#automatic-docs) at `/docs` for testing the API, which would also automatically generate the `curl` command for testing an API endpoint.

Q: ***"When I do a `GET` request, I don't have to add a header and it works. What's the difference with the `POST` request?"***

A: When issuing a `GET` request, there is no request body included, and hence, no request body contents to encode and no need to tell the server what kind of data are  being send. In `GET` requests all parameters must appear in the URL (i.e., the query string) or in a header. While the HTTP standard doesn't define a limit for how long URLs or headers can be, [there is usually a length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request) dependent on both the server and the client (usually between 2KB and 8KB). In a `POST` request, however, the limit is **much** higher and more dependent on the server than the client.